# Different IPv4 numbers from different browsers, same computer

Tags: network, ip, chrome

If I search on Google the words "my ip" **using Firefox**, Google returns a IP that belongs to my ISP:

```
About 447,000,000 results (0.46 seconds) 

200.x.x.x
Your public IP address
```

But, if I made **the same search ("my ip"), on the same computer at the same time using Chrome**, Google returns an IP from a totally different company:

```
About 447,000,000 results (0.46 seconds) 

181.x.x.x
Your public IP address
```

What could be the explanation? Are my ISP or my computer being hacked?

**Update:** If I open http://whatismyipaddress.com/ on Firefox and Chrome, I get the IP number from my ISP, 200.x.x.x. For some reason, Google is giving me a different address on Chrome.

**Update 2:** I was configuring a Security Group for an AWS EC2 server using Firefox. When I clicked on "My IP", most of the times it shows me 200.x.x.x, but sometimes, it shows me 181.x.x.x

Comment: what's the company it reports as?

Comment: What plug-ins do you have on the incorrect browser? Do you have a VPN? Why not post the incorrect IP so we can verify?

Comment: Are you using any sort of network proxy in one of the browsers but not the other?  Also try disabling your browser extensions as some (such as [Hola](https://hola.org/)) can be used to set up such a network proxy.

Comment: How is this an infosec issue?

Comment: @Ulkoma because it looks like the OP's web browsing sessions are being redirected through a third party, and the OP doesn't know why.

Comment: Chrome has a feature to save data and compress it, and if that's on then Google will receive the data to compress it. Is the IP you get when using Chrome related to Google at all?

Answer (score 1):

I am going to assume from the comment

> Update 2: I was configuring a Security Group for an AWS EC2 server using Firefox. When I clicked on "My IP", most of the times it shows me 200.x.x.x, but sometimes, it shows me 181.x.x.x

that this is at your place of work. in many cases businesses have 2 or more ISPs in case one fails. You might have your gateway routers setup to do some sort of load balancing so that sometimes your connection will use the 200.x.x.x and other times it could use the 181.x.x.x.